# inserting into sqlite db-python

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I'm trying to use a SQLite database in my newest python program. I'm trying to insert a new row into my database by using insert. The database's columns are set up as:

```
0|pw|TEXT|0||0
1|Name|TEXT|0||0
2|dataBaseID|INT|0||0
3|email|TEXT|0||0
```

My python code is:

```
this = "INSERT INTO users (pw, name, dataBaseID, email)"
this += " VALUES ("+passWord+", "+UserName+", "+"1"+", "+email+")"
print(this)
cur.execute(this)
dbCon.commit()
```

And the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/process.py", line 267, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/process.py", line 116, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "serverBackend.py", line 85, in main
    add(msg,cur,databaseConnection,connect)
  File "serverBackend.py", line 20, in add
    cur.execute(this)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Chips1994
```

Why Is it throwing an error and indicating that the Im trying to access a column that doesn't exist? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the result of `print(this)`?

Comment: INSERT INTO users (pw, name, dataBaseID, email) VALUES (Chips1994, raddingy, 1, raddingy_msu.edu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to surround your values with `"` or something similar. What you're currently doing is in addition, really bad code and may result in some serious sql injection problems.

As [stated in the official python-sqlite 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), you should use placeholders.

Replace your current code with

```
query = "INSERT INTO users (pw, name, dataBaseID, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
cur.execute(query, (passWord, UserName, 1, email))
cur.commit()
```

Using the placeholder `?`, the sql wrapper will take care to surround the values with necessary characters like `"`.

**Bonus tip:** It seems, that you want to store a password in clear text. You should avoid this and use some hash method like PBKDF2.

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot about that! I'm still in the process of learning sqlite.